# 3 different math books, 2 different physics books are arranged on a bookshelf. In how many ways can they be arranged if no 2 math books are together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The book gave the answer as $12$.

This is how I approached it:

We need the arrangements in the form

math - physics - math - physics - math

or else two math books will be adjacent. So, we choose $2$ positions for the two physics books to be placed and multiply it by $2!$, since either position can have either book. Next, we see that there are three remaining spaces for the math books, so we multiple by $3!$ giving us:

$$ 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 $$

However, since we chose the positions once for the physics books, and then another for the math books, we must divide by $2$ so we don't double count. 
Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think you overcomplicated it a little bit.

Your argument that the arrangement should be

$$
MPMPM
$$

is correct, $M$ standing for math books and $P$ standing for physics.

Now you could basically look at the number of permutations between the $3$ math and $2$ physics books. Which gives

$$
3!\cdot 2!=12
$$

different arrangements.

You can think of this last step as "we know that the books will be in this order $MPMPM$" and this is not changed by swapping two math books for example.

We can in a way decompose this into two parts

$$
M\ \ M\ \ M
$$
and
$$
P\ \ P
$$

and look at the number of ways the individual parts can be arranged and then using product rule to reassamble them.

P.S: I don´t really understand your last paragraph about overcounting. Would you elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: I was wrongly under the impression that we chose the spots for physics books first, then filled in the rest with math books, and then we chose the spots for math books, and then filled the rest with physics books, so we would end up counting the arrangements twice. I don't know why, but in my mind I thought this was right.

Comment: Good! Now we figured out where it went wrong. That is good :) You understand now?

Comment: Yes. So if we use 3!, that means we choose 3 spots to place the math books? And by multiplying it by 2!, we are choosing the other two spots to put the physics books?

Comment: I would put it another way, the spots are fixed and we permute the possible arrangements of the books

Answer (score 0):

There won't be able double counting in this case but you seem to have made a simple error, you have put $2$ for each physics book but once one is in place, there is no choice for the other.  Starting from the left, your choices at each stage are $3, 2, 2, 1, 1$ and hence the answer if $12$.